# Can we know our comment or answer is seen by questioner or not?

Tags: support, answers, comments

When I leave a comment or give an answer, I like to know whether the asker has seen it or not. Sometimes I check their profile to see when they were online, but I can't be sure that they have seen my comment or answer. What can I do to be sure?

Answer (score 8):

There's no way to be sure someone has seen your comment unless they reply to it. Even then, there's no guarantee they *read it completely* or understood it. Many users will open the notification tab and then close it again without actually looking at the notifications within.

Comment: At the very least, they do get a notification. It's in their interest to follow through on answers and comments. Sadly, not everybody does but I occasionally get my answer from *years ago* accepted. So, users might need some time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I mean it is not similar to for example Whatsapp that we can know when our message is read?

Comment: No @Mohammad, Stack Overflow is very, very different from Whatsapp.

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin Stack Overflow is designed to be as little about "the user" as possible. Users are part of SO only as a function of generating questions and answers. For this reason, we don't have some functions that are common in other 'community' websites: following users, 'connecting' with them, seeing read-receipts, ignoring/blocking users, etc. are all not supported because all (permanent) actions are supposed to be focused on content, not people, here.

Comment: Yes, you are right

Comment: I wasn't aware WhatsApp had this integration with my brain that it can decide I have *read* a message. That is pretty amazing.

Comment: When you long click in one message, then you go to info of it and will when it was delivered and it was read.@rene

Comment: Rene was just making a joke; Whatsapp's "Read" notification only tells you that the person has opened the chat containing the message, it doesn't mean the user actually read (or even looked at) the message. To know someone actually read the message, you'd have to read the person's mind.

Comment: @VLAZ _they do get a notification_ Unless there's a [bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394856/message-notification-isnt-working) (since fixed) where notifications don't always go out.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I think it's redundant to say "this is how it works unless there is a bug" because that's true for *every single feature*.

Comment: @VLAZ I thought it worth mentioning because it was a very recent problem