# Message notification isn't working

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications, global-inbox

Is there any recent issue with the message notification? I just noticed new comments on my answer but I wasn't notified.

> [image]

Comment: See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345561/where-are-my-notifications

Comment: and I will not get any notification from this question too ...

Comment: I got a notification from your comment though.

Comment: not from yours ..

Comment: So it's broken for some users and not others since it is working consistently for me here.

Comment: Maybe the servers in the webfarm are doing an involuntary A/B test with us....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A regression bug was introduced here that prevented some (but not all) comment notifications from going out. The issue has been fixed.

Unfortunately there is no practical way for us to requeue the comment notifications that didn't get sent out in the past few hours.